# CSS is broken while loading a web page under an iFrame for safari

Tags: iframe, safari, iframe-resizer

We are trying to load a webpage under an iFrame under safari 13.1
Because of cross site issue CCS is not getting loaded properly.
we are getting message as

"did not parse stylesheet at '....url/abc.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in a strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct mime type for css files on your webserver